# Encountering an error when trying to plot nomogram and ROC curve using the plot function

Tags: r

After building a predictive model using logistic regression, I encountered the following errors when attempting to plot `nomogram` and *ROC* curve to demonstrate the prediction performance:

> Error in UseMethod("plot") :  no applicable method for 'plot' applied to an object of class "nomogram"

and, respectively,

> Error in UseMethod("plot") : #no applicable method for 'plot' applied to an object of class "roc"

### Attempt

```r
library(rms)
library(pROC)
for(i in names(train_data)[c(1,3:9)]) train_data[, i] = as.factor(train_data[, i])
d <- datadist(train_data)
options(datadist="d")
fit <- lrm(Death~Patho_CNB+TP53+PTEN+PIK3CA+NF1+TP53_pathway+RTK_RAS_pathway,
           data = train_data,x=TRUE,y=TRUE)
nom <- nomogram(fit,
                fun = plogis,
                funlabel="Risk of Metastasis")
plot(nom,lp=FALSE)
train_pred <- predict(fit,
                      newdata=train_data,
                      type = "fitted")
train_roc <- roc(train_data$Death,train_pred)
auc(train_roc)
ci(train_roc) 
plot(train_roc)
```

### Toy `train_data`:

```r
train_data = structure(list(Death = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), TMB = c(5.6, 
1.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.4, 4.2, 0.9, 1.4, 4.7, 5.6, 2.8, 6.1, 3.7, 0.9, 
1.9, 1.4, 8.4, 2.8, 0.5, 1.4, 3.3, 2.8, 2.8, 0.9, 1.9, 1.9, 3.3, 
0.5, 0.5, 1.4, 2.3, 1.9, 0.9, 2.3, 3.7, 0.5, 7, 1.9, 1.4, 2.3, 
3.7, 2.3, 1.9, 5.6, 1.4, 7, 0.9, 8.9, 2.3, 1.4, 4.7, 3.3, 2.3, 
12.7, 1.9, 0.9, 2.8, 2.3, 2.3, 1.4, 2.3, 4.2, 6.1, 1.4, 4.7, 
0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 7.5, 5.6, 0.9, 0.5, 1.4, 0.9, 8, 1.9, 2.8, 4.2, 
2.3, 1.4, 27.6, 0.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.4, 1.9, 1.9, 0.9, 0.5, 2.8, 
1.9, 2.8, 10.3, 2.8, 3.7, 1.4, 0.9, 4.2, 1.9, 3.3, 2.8, 2.3, 
0.5, 1.4, 3.7, 1.4, 2.3, 2.8, 0.9, 1.4, 0.5, 1.9, 7.5, 1.4, 2.3, 
2.3, 1.4, 1.4, 0.9, 1.9, 0.9, 2.3, 3.7, 1.9, 3.3, 1.4, 0.9, 1.9, 
1.4, 0.9, 4.7, 0.9, 8, 2.3, 0.9, 17.3, 0.5, 1.9, 2.3, 0.9, 1.4, 
2.3, 0.9, 0.9, 1.4, 2.3, 2.3, 0.5, 2.3, 0.9, 2.3, 7, 2.3, 3.3, 
0.9, 0.5, 2.3, 3.3, 3.3, 0.5, 55.3, 0.5, 1.9, 0.9, 14.5, 0.9, 
0.9, 4.7, 5.6, 1.9, 2.3, 2.8, 1.4, 1.9, 2.8, 1.4, 0.9, 0.5, 1.9, 
2.3, 2.3, 1.9, 1.9, 1.4, 1.9, 4.2, 0.9, 1.4, 0.5, 1.4, 1.9, 0.9, 
0.5, 0.9, 1.9, 6.6, 1.9, 2.8, 1.4, 0.5, 0.9), Patho_CNB = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("IDC", "ILC", "other"
), class = "factor"), TP53 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), PTEN = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    PIK3CA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), NF1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), TP53_pathway = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    RTK_RAS_pathway = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(6L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 14L, 27L, 28L, 30L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 46L, 48L, 51L, 54L, 
58L, 64L, 67L, 70L, 72L, 79L, 81L, 84L, 86L, 90L, 92L, 94L, 95L, 
100L, 102L, 104L, 108L, 117L, 119L, 121L, 122L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 
131L, 132L, 134L, 137L, 140L, 141L, 143L, 145L, 147L, 152L, 158L, 
165L, 167L, 171L, 175L, 176L, 180L, 181L, 184L, 186L, 190L, 192L, 
194L, 199L, 206L, 208L, 210L, 213L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 
221L, 224L, 227L, 232L, 234L, 239L, 240L, 242L, 244L, 246L, 247L, 
253L, 255L, 257L, 259L, 261L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 
269L, 283L, 287L, 290L, 1237L, 1238L, 1242L, 1243L, 1244L, 1245L, 
1248L, 1249L, 1251L, 1252L, 1253L, 1254L, 1257L, 1258L, 1259L, 
1260L, 1263L, 1264L, 1265L, 1266L, 1268L, 1270L, 1271L, 1272L, 
1273L, 1275L, 1276L, 1278L, 1282L, 1283L, 1284L, 1285L, 1288L, 
1289L, 1290L, 1291L, 1292L, 1296L, 1297L, 1298L, 1299L, 1302L, 
1303L, 1307L, 1311L, 1312L, 1314L, 1318L, 1319L, 1321L, 1322L, 
1324L, 1326L, 1328L, 1331L, 1335L, 1339L, 1341L, 1342L, 1343L, 
1347L, 1349L, 1351L, 1354L, 1355L, 1361L, 1366L, 1368L, 1370L, 
1371L, 1374L, 1375L, 1377L, 1385L, 1389L, 1390L, 1395L, 1398L, 
1401L, 1404L, 1407L, 1408L, 1411L, 1415L, 1416L, 1417L, 1422L, 
1423L, 1426L, 1428L, 1431L, 1433L, 1443L, 1446L, 1447L, 1452L, 
1459L, 1460L, 1463L, 1467L, 1470L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: On my machine, your code runs without any issues. Have you tried re-running the code after re-starting your session? Is it due to the toy data? In that case, please replace it with data that causes the errors. I recommend to replace the *for-loop* with `train_data[-2] = lapply(train_data[-2], as.factor)`. Even better: use column names instead of indices. I edited your question, now required libraries are on top of the script.